# New buckets are not displayed in console manager

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Starting last night I've started to experience the following issue:

- Existing buckets I created previously are displayed in the console manager and with gsutil, this is the functionality I expect, however...
- creating a new bucket via console manager will be displayed, but as soon as the page refreshes or I navigate elsewhere and come back the bucket isn't listed anymore
  -- using gsutil to list the project buckets gives me the older ones but not the new one
  -- trying to create a new bucket with the same name (via console mngr or gsutil) gives me an error that the bucket already exists
  -- using gsutil rm -R  successfully removes the bucket, so it was in fact there

Is there an issue or 'feature' of gs clould storage I'm now aware of?

Comment: How long did you wait between creating the bucket and trying to view the page. Bucket listing is eventually consistent. It can take some time for new buckets to appear in bucket listings. Did the problem persist for more than a minute or two?

Comment: something is up today... the GCS console isn't showing me keys that I can see via gsutil... and even gsutil is inconsistently returning results (I can run a **gsutil ls** on a bucket 10 times in a row and half of them will return keys, and the other half return nothing at all)

Comment: That's the funny thing, I create the bucket (using the console mngr) and I'm immediately taken to that bucket, if I return to the bucket's home it is there and listed alongside my other buckets, but once I refresh the page it's gone (not displayed). I waited all night figuring it was just me or a quirk on the GCS side but they are still not listed in the console mngr or gsutil, yet I can manually edit the URL in my browser to the bucket path and I get there.

Comment: ...And automagically the problem seems to have gone away. I'm replicating the same steps as before and now the bucket get's listed every time.

Comment: This was an operational issue earlier today in which the eventually consistent listings were slower to update than normal.  We've resolved the issue, but please keep in mind the eventually consistent nature of Cloud Storage listings when building your applications.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it refers to an operational issue of Cloud Storage, rather than an API and/or programming question. For operational issues, please contact Google directly via the address referenced here: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/resources-support#community

Comment: Just to be clear, I did that. From the page you're referring to: "If you have any questions or encounter any problems with Google Cloud Storage, please first read the FAQ. If you still need help, please post your question to Stack Overflow. Along with the large and active Stack Overflow community, our team will be actively monitoring your posts and answering questions with the tag google-cloud-storage."